# Expected Value: Animal Cages

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The Happy Animals Kennel has $18$ cages in a row. They allocate these cages at random to $6$ dogs, $6$ cats, and $6$ pot-bellied pigs (with one animal per cage). All arrangements are equally likely.

Let $A$ be the number of times in the row of cages that two animals of the same species are adjacent. For example, in the arrangement DCPCDPPPDCDPCDCCPD (where D=dog, C=cat, and P=pig), we have $A=3$.

What is the expected value of $A$?

UPDATE: Oops, I forgot to include what I've got so far!  It would be almost impossible to list all of the possibilities and expected value is a new topic for me, so I'm fuzzy on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the [Linearity of Expectations](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).  For $i\in \{1,\cdots,17\}$ let $X_i$ be the indicator variable telling you whether Cage $i$ contains the same animal as Cage $i+1$ (thus $X_i=1$ if the two animals match, and $0$ otherwise).  Then $E[X_i]=\frac 5{17}$ and the answer you want is $$E=E\left[\sum X_i\right]=\sum E[X_i]=17\times \frac 5{17}=5$$

Comment: Thanks for answering, lulu!

Comment: Nice approach. Nice ref! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have  three types of animals, $A,B$  and $C.$ Construct the
generating function of strings over this alphabet classified according
to the last letter with adjacent equal letters marked. We get

$$F_A(z) - a = va F_A(z) + a F_B(z) + a F_C(z)$$

and

$$F_B(z) - b = b F_A(z) + vb F_B(z) + b F_C(z)$$

and finally

$$F_C(z) - c = c F_A(z) + c F_B(z) + vc F_C(z).$$

We are interested in 
$$Q_{A,B,C} (z) =
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} F_{A,B,C}(z)\right|_{v=1}.$$

We get

$$Q_A(z) = \left.aF_A(z)\right|_{v=1} + aQ_A(z)
+ a Q_B(z) + a Q_C(z).$$

and two more that are cyclic iterates. We require

$$P(z) = Q_A(z) + Q_B(z) + Q_C(z)$$

which yields by adding the cyclic iterates

$$P(z) = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{1-a-b-c} + (a+b+c) P(z)$$

or

$$P(z) = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{(1-a-b-c)^2}.$$

To extract the coefficient on this restrict to the number 
of animals of each type being equal say $M$ to get

$$\left([a^{M-2} b^M c^M] +
[a^M b^{M-2} c^M] +
[a^M b^M c^{M-2}] \right) 
\sum_{q=0}^\infty (q+1) (a+b+c)^q
\\ = 3\times (3M-1) \times {3M-2\choose M, M, M-2}.$$

With $M=6$  i.e. six animals of  each type the  expectation thus works
out to

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{18\choose 6,6,6}^{-1}
\times 3 \times 17 \times {16\choose 6,6,4}
= 5.}$$

The generic formula is

$${3M\choose M,M,M}^{-1} \times 3\times (3M-1)\times
{3M-2\choose M,M,M-2}
\\ = \frac{1}{3M} \times 3 \times M (M-1)$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
M-1.}$$

**Remark.** Observe that we did not  in fact need to solve any systems
of equations.

Comment: Interesting approach! (+1)